# time tracking application on Linux

Tags: linux, productivity, time-management

what application do you guys use for time tracking in Linux.
I am interested in an application that tracks what applications I use, similar to rescuetime but with will run on Linux since the Linux uploader doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Maybe the solution could be to look at solving the problem with the Linux uploader?  What problem are you having with it?

Comment: it doesnt upload the time spent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** Wakoopa is no longer time tracking software, so the link below is no longer relevant.

---

Check out [Wakoopa](http://wakoopa.com). It will give you options on what applications to track, with your statistics nicely displayed on the web site. Linux, Mac, and Windows tracking clients are available.

Comment: i started using it a week ago, looks nice .. but it doesn't give me a detailed report on productivity like rescuetime :(

Comment: As someone else pointed out on a related answer of mine, the software by the name Wakoopa is no longer a time tracking program. :) I've edited the answer to state this, but feel free to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I got the rescuetime uploader to work on Ubuntu 10.04 by editing these two rescuetime .server files:

here is the entire install process

```
wget http://launchpad.net/rescuetime-linux-uploader/trunk/99/+download/rescuetime-linux-uploader-99.tar.bz2
tar xvjf rescuetime-linux-uploader-99.tar.bz2
emacs-snapshot rescuetime-linux-uploader-99/README &
sudo apt-get install epiphany-extensions
python setup.py build 
firefox firefox_extension/rescuetime-firefox-extension.xpi
#install extension in google chrome through browser
```

next you have to change the directory from `/usr/bin` to `/usr/lib/bin` on the third line in  `rescuetime_tracker.server` and `rescuetime_notifier.server` found in `/usr/lib/bonobo/server/`

This can be done in a text editor or on the command line using `sed`:

```
 cd /usr/lib/bonobo/servers/
 sudo su
 for i in rescuetime*.server
 do
   sed -i 's/\/usr\/bin\/rescuetime/\/usr\/local\/bin\/rescuetime/g' $i
 done
```