# How can I track how I spend time on my Linux computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [time tracking application on linux](https://superuser.com/questions/82058/time-tracking-application-on-linux)

Every Linux time-tracking application I've seen assumes you're tracking time for projects, perhaps to create invoices later for your clients. This is not what I'm looking for.

Rather, I just want some insight into how I spend my time on my computer. I'd like to waste less time on my computer, and spend my time on more productive tasks. The first step to improving anything is to measure it. But I can't be bothered or remember to click on some icon and switch "projects" every time I change from my terminal to browsing youtube, or something like that. I want the time I spend on different applications tracked automatically.

If there's no app that can do this already, I'll write a basic version myself. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel.